# Genesys Workspace Desktop Edition out of service

Tags: genesys, workspace-desktop-edition

Workspace Desktop Edition get out of service automatically after login, where did the problem come from?

Comment: Add logs or something more usefull to try to help you

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are talking about a SIP Server...then problem could be your PC or your network. 
You need to check WDE logs (sip endpoint as well).
Next time you ask something at least post some logs or details on your infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

Check the following things,

1. Agent is having required Access Group
2. Place DN and Agent's DN are under same Switch or not
3. SIP End point is running or not.
4. Check network